# List the (direct!) children of the elements of an xml-document using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, children

I am trying to analyse a complex xml-file using xsl.

I managed to list all elements an their respective parents with this code:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
   <xsl:stylesheet version = "2.0" 
      xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match = "/"> 
  <xsl:for-each select="//element()">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/><xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I list the (direct!) children of each element, too?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: What do you want to list, the name of child elements, the value of child elements or nodes in general? What format do you want?

Comment: And if you know how to select an element with XPath then you shouldn't have difficulties to find out how to select child elements, the spec has all the details https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a simple list format, this just reworks your sample XSL code to add in output of direct child names.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//element()">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>
        <!-- Direct children:
        The `*` here in the `select` statement just selects 
        all child elements.  This could also be expressed
        (perhaps more clearly, but also more verbosely) as
        either of the following:
            ./*
            child::*
        -->
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <!-- We put the semicolon before each child's name.
                That way, if there are no children, we don't have
                an extraneous semicolon after the parent's name.-->
            <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```